# Update MYSQL query of column's substring form different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

How can i update column value of one table by comparing sub string column value of another table with sub string column value of main table(first 9 character have to compare).
Like : Table 1

```
ID       Text            ValueToSet
1        Chris0123-!@#   updated_value
2        John
3        Paul
```

Table2

```
ID       Text               ValueToSet
1        Mitchell Johnson   ABC
2        Chris0123@N/A      DEF
3        Steven             GHI
```

"updated_value" have to updated as "DEF".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be looking for an UPDATE with a JOIN :

```
UPDATE table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 
    ON t2.text LIKE CONCAT('%', t1.text, '%')
SET t1.table2id = t2.id
```

---

After OP was edited, here is a solution to compare the first 9 characters of the strings, using SUBSTR()

```
UPDATE table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 
    ON SUBSTR(t2.text, 1, 9) =  SUBSTR(t1.text, 1, 9)
SET t1.table2id = t2.id
```

Comment: i have to compare Chris0123 with Chris0123@N/A and update  "updated_value" in table1->Table2ID as shown in example.i.e.- first 8 char have to compare.

Comment: can u help me if i have to compare only 7 chars??

Comment: @KumarVivek : this was not exactly your original question... So you want to compare the first 8 chars of both fields and if they are the same then update ?

Comment: exactly... as you asked me in your previous reply.